# i want to make adialog in my app appear in time such as every 30 min every appear with new text

Tags: android

I want to make a dialog in my application appear in Specified time such as every 30 min 
 Every time with new text In the Dialog

Comment: That is interesting requirement. What have you tried so far. Can you share code for that? You can get help here after you have shown some effort on your own.

Comment: I'm thinking of a new project, I will use when this feature, so I wonder how they are implemented

Comment: You will not get answers about "how" to do something here unless you show what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a handler to make a dialog box appear every 30s. Here is an example of a handler. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/